# Separate TFS Build excluding a single project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, build, sandcastle

I have a solution that currently builds nicely in TFS. I have just added a **Sandcastle help File Builder** project to it so that the help files can be generated. Now the solutions takes ages to build locally (it has also doubled the build time on the TFS Server).

In practice I'd be happy generating the help files once per day, or only when specifically requested as part of a build.

I tried creating a separate solution (for a new build) which included the Sandcastle project but I got a warning saying that the projects were already under source control.

What is the best way to configure TFS/the solution for this sort of situation? Can I have two builds that run on separate schedules and include/exclude certain projects in the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new [solution configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx) that excludes building your help project. Then in your TFS build you can [specify which configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx#configs) to build. You could have a CI build that doesn't include your help project, and then a nightly build that includes everything.